# Restore SBS 2003 CompanyWeb calendar from flat files?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs-2003

Ok so I have a job of recovering a calendar that was used for an event schedule. The situation is that there was never a backup done except for using Carbonite on the C drive. I have re-installed the server with the same server name and domain. I tried stopping the mssqlsharepoint service and over-righting the two DB files (STS_*1.mdf and STS*_1_log.LDF) and each one individually each time stopping and restarting the service. Now I knew before I started that this had a slim chance of working but I had to try because everything else i could find involved backing up before restoring and this just wasn't done.

Please someone help it is driving me mad I tell you MADDDDDD.

ps i am not the genius that set this up just the fool tasked to clean up the mess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my situation I just needed the data from the old database what I found out is that I could just use the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express to mount and export the data to a flat SQL file and restored the data from there.